# map function return undefined

Tags: javascript, function, methods

Down below, you see a simple map function for array, and I can't figure it out why I have `undefined` when I call `index[0]`.

When I call `return index`, I got array of numbers. so they exist!

Source:

```js
let aRa = [
  { hero: "troll"   , age: 12 , hair: "red"    },
  { hero: "rikky"   , age: 11 , hair: "purple" },
  { hero: "techies" , age: 40 , hair: "yellow" }
]

let joyRide = aRa.map(function(item, index, array) {
  return index[0];
});

console.log(joyRide)
```

Source code image:

[image: source code]

Comment: `index[0];` will always be undefined because it's a number.

Comment: `index` is a number. What do you expect `index[0]` to be?

Comment: What is this code supposed to do? Right now it's meaningless and there is no description for what the goal is.

Comment: I am also not sure what you are trying to do. What do you want the function in .map to do? Here is the docs for array.prototype.map() https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second parameter of the call back function of [`Array.prototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) is the index that have numeric value, using index on them will always return `undefined`.

To access the first key from each object in the array you can try the following using [`Destructuring assignment`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment):

```js
let aRa = [
        {hero:"troll",
        age:12,
        hair:"red",},
        
        {hero:"rikky",
        age:11,
        hair:"purple"},
        
        {hero:"techies",
        age:40,
        hair:"yellow"},
    ]

let joyRide = aRa.map(({hero}) => hero);
console.log(joyRide)
```

Answer (score 0):

The second parameter of the callback passed into [Array.prototype.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) gets a number. You are trying to index a number and getting undefined.

Comment: how to call first element in firts key?
mean hero property in 1 key in array

Comment: @N_is_my_name what does _"first element in firts key"_ mean?

Comment: @N_is_my_name What would you like the output to look like?

Comment: value of property(hero)

Comment: @N_is_my_name that'd be `item.key`?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pluck keys, you can use the object destructuring assignment hen mapping to extract individual key-value pairs referenced by the key.

```js
const heroes = [
  { hero: "troll"   , age: 12 , hair: "red"    },
  { hero: "rikky"   , age: 11 , hair: "purple" },
  { hero: "techies" , age: 40 , hair: "yellow" }
]

const names      = heroes.map(({ hero }) => hero);
const ages       = heroes.map(({ age  }) => age);
const hairColors = heroes.map(({ hair }) => hair);

console.log(`Names       : ${names.join(', ')}`     );
console.log(`Ages        : ${ages.join(', ')}`      );
console.log(`Hair Colors : ${hairColors.join(', ')}`);
```

If you want the first item, in the array, you can also use object destructuring.

```js
const heroes = [
  { hero: "troll"   , age: 12 , hair: "red"    },
  { hero: "rikky"   , age: 11 , hair: "purple" },
  { hero: "techies" , age: 40 , hair: "yellow" }
]

const [ first ] = heroes;

console.log(first);

const [ { hero: firstName } ] = heroes;

console.log(firstName);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you mean to get the 'hero' of first element, you get it via

```
console.log(aRa[0].hero)
```

If you want to get the hero element of all items and map it in a new array, you should do

```
let aRa = [
  { hero: "troll"   , age: 12 , hair: "red"    },
  { hero: "rikky"   , age: 11 , hair: "purple" },
  { hero: "techies" , age: 40 , hair: "yellow" }
]

let joyRide = [];
for (i = 0; i<aRa.length; i++) {
  joyRide.push(aRa[i].hero);
}

console.log(joyRide)
```

Answer (score 0):

Map function it automatically executes loop according to the length of the array on which map function is called. In your case this will work for you..

```
let joyRide = aRa.map(function(item, index, array) {
  return item; 
});
```

If you want to get array of heros than

```
 let joyRide = aRa.map(function(item, index, array) {
      return item.hero;
    });
```

**Explaination**

/* when first time loop executes */

**item** will have value  **`{ hero: "troll"   , age: 12 , hair: "red"    }`**

**index** will have value **0**

**array** will have value

```
[
  { hero: "troll"   , age: 12 , hair: "red"    },
  { hero: "rikky"   , age: 11 , hair: "purple" },
  { hero: "techies" , age: 40 , hair: "yellow" }
]
```

/* when second time loop executes */

**item** will have value  **`{ hero: "rikky"   , age: 11 , hair: "purple" }`**

**index** will have value **1**

**array** will have value

```
[
  { hero: "troll"   , age: 12 , hair: "red"    },
  { hero: "rikky"   , age: 11 , hair: "purple" },
  { hero: "techies" , age: 40 , hair: "yellow" }
]
```

and so on till the length of the array..